# Please help me log on to Azure server (simple ssh doesn't work)

Tags: ssh, azure, ssh-keys

I have been trying to log on to my Azure server's Virtual Machine that's running on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS for hours. I would appreciate it a lot if someone could help me.

1. I generated new ssh keys

   ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your_email@example.com"
   ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
2. I generated a .pem file

   openssl req -x509 -new -days 365 -key id_rsa -out id_rsa.x509req.pem
3. I tried to log in with ssh

   ssh thistimeinst.cloudapp.net -vvv

**But it asks for a password, but I didn't input any password when creating the keys.**

This is the log

```
maxuimbp:.ssh max$ ssh mywebsite.cloudapp.net -v
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to mywebsite.cloudapp.net [137.116.167.0] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/max/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/max/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/max/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/max/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 3f:44:3f:91:dd:7b:15:fb:5f:c7:64:14:df:bc:3f:21
debug1: Host 'mywebsite.cloudapp.net' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/max/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/max/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/max/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/max/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
max@mywebsite.cloudapp.net's password:
```

I thought I did everything perfectly. Does anyone know why this is happening to me?

Comment: Did you happen to add the public key to the authorized keys on the target?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not asking for a password for the key, it's asking for a password for the account your trying to log on to as the key based methods have failed.

Comment: Thank you lain, the problem was that I was doing `ssh mymusic.cloudapp.net` but I should've done `ssh username@mymusic.cloudapp.net`